# PHP exception overwirte toString()

Tags: php, oop, tostring

I'm having problems with my own exception class: `IOExeption`. I want it to have another output then the normal exception class but in spite of the code below, its output is still the same.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
class IOExeption extends Exception
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        $string  = '<h1 class="text-warning text-center">';
        $string .= $this->getMessage();
        $string .= '</h1>';
        return $string;
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you have any uncaught exception handler defined?

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact, **exceptions should have no output at all**.

Whatever output have to be done **in the exception handler only**. And only in case it is development server which the only user you are. Otherwise it have to **log the error message in plain text.**